# Single threading to Multithreading in the middle of a computation, is it possible?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu, computational-geometry

Given the inherent complexity of multi-threaded programming, can we explore the practicality and level of difficulty involved in introducing threads into an already executing code?

For example: Assume I am doing a bunch of simulations where the run time varies greatly. If I split the number of available threads equally for each run, is it feasible to add the freed threads from the shorter simulations to the longer.

I'm raising this question because I've come across a commercial software application that operates under similar principles. In this software, the availability of multi-threading licenses is limited, obtaining additional licenses can be expensive, and interrupting ongoing simulations is often infeasible.

Note: the software runs on CPU only.

Oversimplified answers are welcome :)

Thank you all !

Comment: If each simulation can be broken into smaller chunks, then yeah, you could do the equivalent of OpenMP schedule=dynamic.  Obviously you have to write your code to be able to break the remaining work into batches when more worker threads become available, otherwise you have no work for a spare CPU to do.

Comment: Are you asking how to write your code so that work is dynamically distributed to all available threads, or wherever it’s possible to modify an existing closed-source application to do this?